# How to changes "15.49" in string array , int values in c#

Tags: c#

I have a question. how to changes "15.49" in **string array to int value** in c#?

Comment: Your question is not clear. `"15.49"` is a `string`, not a string array (`string[]`). Is the dot (`.`) supposed to be a separator? If yes, do you want to retrun an `int` array or just the first number. If not, do you want  `"15.49"`  to be interpreted as number with decimal part and to either truncate or round (which one?) it to an `int`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, your culture uses "," as decimal separator, instead of ".". You could use overload of decimal.Parse to use custom culture format. Since you want to ignore the decimal part, you can use Int32.Convert to fetch the int part.

```
var stringValue = "15,49";
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

var result = Convert.ToInt32( decimal.Parse(stringValue, culture));
```

This would give your the required result

Comment: I want 15. When Double.Parse is used it makes 1549.

Comment: The result was again 1549.

Comment: @AnılGüngördü, is `.` interpreted as thousands separator in your culture?

Comment: result 15 does not happen. the result is 1549.

Comment: @AnılGüngördü Looks like your region uses "," as decimal separator. Could you check the updated code

Comment: thnk u. He took care of.

Answer (score 0):

(int)decimal.Parse("15.49"); - if string null, parse return exception (maybe its what you want)
(int)Convert.ToDecimal("15.49"); if string null, convert return 0

Answer (score -1):

If i am not wrong you want to convert string "15.49" into int ??? If yes then you can use this code `Convert.toInt32("15.49");`

Comment: I get an error using int. System.FormatException: 'The input string was not in the correct format'

Comment: Is "15.49" string or array of characters in your code?

Comment: Or whether it's "15.49" or "15,49" ?